# Sort the dataframe and then write the resulting set to excel in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which has multiple columns, I want to sort by lets say 'developer' and then write the resulting dataframe to another new excel sheet?.

```
workItems = pd.read_csv('dev_assignments.csv')
workItems.Developer.sort_values()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
workItems.to_excel(writer,'Developer')
writer.save()
```

The above does not work.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which error do you get? Please elaborate "does not work".

Answer (score 6):

You are using sort_values() wrong, please see the correct method below. I would also suggest using to_excel instead of ExcelWriter.

```
workItems = pd.read_csv('dev_assignments.csv')
workItems.sort_values('developer').to_excel('dev_assignments_sorted.xlsx')
```

Comment: @Nagender if this answer solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). - AlexG: It would be better if you could provide an explanation as to what the issue was and does your code solves it. Code-only answers are frowned upon and can be deleted on reviews. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to avoid adding the new column with the number to the excel ?